# Fail to download file using Google Document List + oAuth REST protocol

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-docs-api, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client, oauth2-playground

By using the following tool [oAuth Playground](https://code.google.com/oauthplayground/), and following the documentation [Google Documents List API version 3.0](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#downloading_documents_and_files). Here is what I had done.

1. I get access token for the following 3 scopes. `https://docs.google.com/feeds/ https://docs.googleusercontent.com/ https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/`. Please refer to the following attachment.

   [image]
2. After getting access token and refresh token, I begin to make query, to get the download URL for a particular document. I made the following GET request `https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/?v=3`. The respond is something more or less like

---

```
<entry ...
    ...
    <content type='application/zip' src='https://doc-0s-84-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/4t...626&amp;e=download&amp;gd=true'/>
    ...
</entry>
```

3. I then key in the download URL `https://doc-0s-84-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/4t...626&amp;e=download&amp;gd=true`. The result looks like this.

[image]

However, I am getting the following respond.

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Status: 302
Content-length: 0
Via: HTTP/1.1 GWA
Set-cookie: AUTH_98m5tbqk1ftn500bl9bsjcrv52agg3u2_nonce=mupodp3rtqnoc; Domain=doc-0s-84-docs.googleusercontent.com; Expires=Thu, 14-Jun-2012 08:33:15 GMT; Path=/docs/securesc/4t66vjvgb1974sathdoeioitbft52pel; Secure; HttpOnly
Expires: Thu, 14 Jun 2012 08:23:15 GMT
X-google-cache-control: remote-fetch
Server: HTTP Upload Server Built on Jun 7 2012 12:49:38 (1339098578)
Location: https://docs.google.com/nonceSigner?nonce=mupodp3rtqnoc&continue=https://doc-0s-84-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/4t66vjvgb1974sathdoeioitbft52pel/kea7kv7gjen26s72ovuvc0lc9to7ogf7/1339660800000/06447459084918146340/06447459084918146340/0B3MN1kmYytfaNWIwMzYzYzYtNmUxNS00OWMzLThkYzctZmUyNjg5MTY2NmUw?amp;gd%3Dtrue%26amp;e%3Ddownload%26h%3D16653014193614665626&hash=rtv0rrnj8bal21va48shlckqbjf5gjhm
Cache-control: private, max-age=0
Date: Thu, 14 Jun 2012 08:23:15 GMT
P3p: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info."
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

I get the same result, even though I append `?v=3` at the back of URL which makes it looks like `https://doc-0s-84-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/4t...626&amp;e=download&amp;gd=true?v=3`

Any idea on why I am getting such error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL you are using is URL encoded. Simply change `&amp;e=download&amp;gd=true` to `&e=download&gd=true` in the URL.